# API Only sends 1 chunk of metadata when called

Tags: node.js, postgresql, smartcontracts

I have a problem with my API that sends metadata when called from my smart contract of website. Its NFT tokens and my database is postgres and API is node.js
The problem is when I mint 1 NFT metadata works perfect, but if I mint 2 or more it will only ever send 1 chunk of data? So only 1 NFT will mint properly and the rest with no data?

Do I need to set a loop function or delay? Does anyone have any experience with this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the code from the "controller" folder labeled "nft.js"

```
const models = require("../../models/index");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
  create_nft: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const dir = path.resolve(__dirname + `../../../data/traitsfinal.json`);
      const readCards = fs.readFileSync(dir, "utf8");

      const parsed = JSON.parse(readCards);
      console.log("ya data ha final ??", parsed);
      parsed.forEach(async (item) => {
        // return res.json(item)
        let newNft = await models.NFT.create({
          name: item.Name,
          description: item.Description,
          background: item.Background,
          body: item.Body,
          mouth: item.Mouth,
          eyes: item.Eyes,
          head_gear: item.Head_Gear,
          tokenId: item.tokenId,
          image: item.imagesIPFS,
        });
      });

      return res.json({
        data: "nft created",
        error: null,
        success: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("server error", error.message);
      next(error);
    }
  },

  get_nft: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { id } = req.params;
      // console.log("id ?????????",id)
      // console.log("type of  ",typeof(id))
      // const n=Number(id)
      // console.log("type of  ",typeof(id))
      const nft = await models.NFT.findByPk(id);

      if (!nft) {
        throw new Error("Token ID invalid");
      }

      if (!nft.isMinted) {
        throw new Error("Token not minted");
      }
      console.log(nft);
      // }
      const resObj = {
        name: nft.name,
        description: nft.description,
        image: `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${nft.image}`,
        attributes: [
          { trait_type: "background", value: `${nft.background}` },
          { trait_type: "body", value: `${nft.body}` },
          { trait_type: "mouth", value: `${nft.mouth}` },
          { trait_type: "eyes", value: `${nft.eyes}` },
          { trait_type: "tokenId", value: `${nft.tokenId}` },
          {
            display_type: "number",
            trait_type: "Serial No.",
            value: id,
            max_value: 1000,
          },
        ],
      };

      return res.json(resObj);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("server error", error.message);
      next(error);
    }
  },
  get_nft_all: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      // console.log("id ?????????",id)
      // console.log("type of  ",typeof(id))
      // const n=Number(id)
      // console.log("type of  ",typeof(id))
      const nft = await models.NFT.findAndCountAll({
        limit: 10
      });
      // console.log(nft);
      if (!nft) {
        throw new Error("Token ID invalid");
      }

      // if (nft.isMinted) {
      //   throw new Error("Token not minted");
      // }
      // console.log(nft);
      // }
        var resObjarr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < nft.rows.length; i++) {
           resObj = {
            name: nft.rows[i].name,
            description: nft.rows[i].description,
            image: `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${nft.rows[i].image}`,
            attributes: [
              { trait_type: "background", value: `${nft.rows[i].background}` },
              { trait_type: "body", value: `${nft.rows[i].body}` },
              { trait_type: "mouth", value: `${nft.rows[i].mouth}` },
              { trait_type: "eyes", value: `${nft.rows[i].eyes}` },
              { trait_type: "tokenId", value: `${nft.rows[i].tokenId}` },
              {
                display_type: "number",
                trait_type: "Serial No.",
                value: nft.rows[i].id,
                max_value: 1000,
              },
            ],
          };
          resObjarr.push(resObj);
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(resObjarr))
      return res.json(resObjarr);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("server error", error.message);
      next(error);
    }
  },
  mint: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { id } = req.params;
      const updated = await models.NFT.findByPk(id);

      if (!updated) {
        throw new Error("NFT ID invalid");
      }
      if (updated.isMinted) {
        throw new Error("NFT Already minted");
      }
      updated.isMinted = true;
      updated.save();

      return res.json({
        data: "Token minted successfully",
        error: null,
        success: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("server error", error.message);
      next(error);
    }
  },
};
```

Below is from the routes folder.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const auth=require("../middleware/auth")


const {
    create_nft,
    get_nft,
    get_nft_all,
    mint

} = require("../controller/nft");
router.post(
  "/create",
  create_nft
);


router.get(
    "/metadata/:id",
    get_nft
);

router.get(
    "/metadata",
    get_nft_all
);

router.put(
  "/mint/:id",
  mint
);


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I may possibly need an endpoint for each token but I need some help on what this exacly means?

Comment: what do you mean with "mint" 1 NFT in your system? Does it is stored in database, sent to another API... ?

Comment: Yes I have a database with my tokens stored then I call the mint function from a separate API.
The mint function should call as many lines of data as I mint but it only ever sends 1 line. IT seems my API only calls 1 line of data even when requesting 2 or more.

Comment: can you provide some snap code to understand better the issue? I didn't get the order of things happen

Comment: Sure I will provide some of the code that calls the database. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have edited the main post with the code that I believe calls the mint function, its in the controller folder? I am not sure if this is the code you require but please let me know if you want something else?
I am semi new to this but know enough to have built and got this working, I only have this mystery problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code,you may having some kind of asyncrhonous issue in this part:

```js
      parsed.forEach(async (item) => {
        // return res.json(item)
        let newNft = await models.NFT.create({
          name: item.Name,
          description: item.Description,
          background: item.Background,
          body: item.Body,
          mouth: item.Mouth,
          eyes: item.Eyes,
          head_gear: item.Head_Gear,
          tokenId: item.tokenId,
          image: item.imagesIPFS,
        });
      });
```

Because `.forEach` is a function to be used in synchronous context and `NFT.create` returns a promise (that is async). So things happens out of order.

So one approach is to process the data first and then perform a batch operation using `Promise.all`.

```js
    const data = parsed.map(item => {
       return models.NFT.create({
          name: item.Name,
          description: item.Description,
          background: item.Background,
          body: item.Body,
          mouth: item.Mouth,
          eyes: item.Eyes,
          head_gear: item.Head_Gear,
          tokenId: item.tokenId,
          image: item.imagesIPFS,
        })
    })

    const results = await Promise.all(data)
```

The main difference here is `Promise.all` `resolves` the N promises `NFT.create` in an async context in paralell. But if you are careful about the number of concurrent metadata that `data` may be too big to process in parallel, then you can use an async iteration provided by [bluebird's Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) library.

```js
    const Promise = require('bluebird')

    const data = await Promise.map(parsed, item => {
       return models.NFT.create({
          name: item.Name,
          description: item.Description,
          background: item.Background,
          body: item.Body,
          mouth: item.Mouth,
          eyes: item.Eyes,
          head_gear: item.Head_Gear,
          tokenId: item.tokenId,
          image: item.imagesIPFS,
        })
    })

    return data
```

Comment: Thank you, I will deploy this change first thing in the morning, I was looking at the same piece of code so thank you.

Comment: Its not giving me the "token not minted" error. Do I need to change anything else or only that snippet of code?

Comment: Well, it should throw an error even in loop as it is inside a try-catch block